# Extract main page results with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been struggling to extract all the property results from the main search page (https://just.property/property/residential/sale/cape-town-western-cape/); each property is stored within a single div class so I am not quite sure how to access all of them.
I have tried to access a single property using

```
results = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-8"]/div[@class="results"]/div[@id="2259870"]/div[@class="prop-details"]/text()').getall()
```

but I always get an empty array. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The search result for the mentioned website comes from the API call:

```
https://just.property/includes/doSearch.php
```

You need to simulate this call to collect the required information

it should be something like this:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'just.property',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'https://just.property',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://just.property/property/residential/sale/cape-town-western-cape/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.5',
    'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=7347564fa5f107ddd1d368a28ef4fc8e; _ga=GA1.2.21988185.1600678549; _gid=GA1.2.1286094223.1600678549; search=%7B%22area%22%3A%22cape-town-western-cape%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Sale%22%2C%22property_types%22%3A%22%22%2C%22min%22%3A%22100000%22%2C%22max%22%3A%2235000000%22%2C%22beds%22%3A%220%22%2C%22baths%22%3A%220%22%2C%22start%22%3A%220%22%2C%22limit%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22order%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22zone%22%3A%22residential%22%2C%22on_show%22%3A%220%22%7D; _gat=1',
}

data = {
  'area': 'cape-town-western-cape',
  'type': 'Sale',
  'min': '100000',
  'max': '35000000',
  'zone': 'residential',
  'beds': '0',
  'baths': '0',
  'start': '0',
  'limit': '20'
}

response = requests.post('https://just.property/includes/doSearch.php', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: when I try to do that i get the "Raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None"
here is the code :
        import requests
        url='https://just.property/includes/doSearch.php'
        return requests.get(url).json()
not sure what I am doing wrong. @Roman

Comment: Please check the network tab in Chrome for that request. and create the same request with the same headers at least